# ImportError: No module named functools_lrc_cache (discord.py bot)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, discord.py

I'm trying to set up a Discord modmail bot and host it on my Raspberry Pi, however I seem to be getting a traceback error that ends with ImportError: No module named functools_lrc_cache. I'm using Python 3.7 and pipenv to run the bot.py file. What could I do to resolve it?

Here below is the full Traceback error and the steps I'm following for selfhosting the bot: https://taaku18.github.io/modmail/local-hosting/

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/bin/pipenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1236, in invoke
    return Command.invoke(self, ctx)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 204, in cli
    clear=state.clear,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 580, in ensure_project
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 498, in ensure_virtualenv
    python = ensure_python(three=three, python=python)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 388, in ensure_python
    path_to_python = find_a_system_python(python)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 347, in find_a_system_python
    from .vendor.pythonfinder import Finder
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import SystemPath, WindowsFinder
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/models/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..utils import KNOWN_EXTS, unnest
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/utils.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .compat import Path, lru_cache, TimeoutError  # noqa
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/compat.py", line 15, in <module>
    from backports.functools_lru_cache import lru_cache  # type: ignore  # noqa
ImportError: No module named functools_lru_cache
```

Comment: Are you sure you are running the app in a Python 3 environment? The traceback shows references to Python 2.7.

Comment: The repo code is in Python 3.7, but if I'm in a Python 2.7 environment, how would I check that and switch to a Python 3 environment?

Comment: where's the actual code?

Comment: https://github.com/kyb3r/modmail is the actual repo, https://taaku18.github.io/modmail/local-hosting/ is the selfhosting guide I'm following to selfhost on my Raspberry Pi (using the Linux instructions).